# How could we encourage people with more privileges to prefer doing tasks requiring more privileges?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, moderation

My reputation at the time I am writing this post is ~1000. I can review few queues and flag and edit posts. What has began to bother me a bit is that sometimes about a half of my edits can be rejected by the Community with reason

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit

Not the reject itself bothers me but with these two things together when reject happens:

- My edits might be "overridden" by people that have from 8K to 16K reputation
- At the same time there can be 88 edits -which of 5 is mine, luckily not "overridden" yet- waiting for approval and 10 of my flags pending for hours

The problem is not that if edits and flags pend for a long time but as a small problem I feel that

- It just is frustrating to do the edit job in vain. And the more people work on any queue the more there will be conflicts in edits
- Queues requiring less reputation most probably have more editors available -those are anyway consumed in a quite short period of time - and the effort that high rep person puts in a low rep queue is - at least at some scale - out off high rep queues

**Update**: an example case if someone can see how in this case resources could have been used better. Please pay attention to the editing & approving times

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18175865

In this particular my semi-approved edit was overridden 42 minutes after I did it. Instead of making my work vain my edit could only have been approved / improved or whatever else than just overriding it without any explanation what was wrong with it.

Comment: That last edit you suggested was over turned by the OP. That one always wins. For the other edits it is indeed true that both you and higher reps are working of the same list, leading to conflicts. Beyond that: flag handling takes time, sometimes a lot of time and it is weekend and I'm slacking. So that is basically it.

Comment: @rene Yes I am aware about these facts and I tried to express in the title and in the ending question what I am after. I tried to suggest implicitly - and hopefully discreet enough - that when people with high rep "waste their time" to  "wrong" things edit approval & flag handling will take longer also.

Comment: Alternatively, go for [questions with the highest (long-term) impact](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120907/highest-view-rate-questions-non-community-wiki-4).

Comment: I'm not sure what your request is - making edits is generally faster than thoughtful reviewing (because you edit things you are sure about, but to review you get a lot of changes that you may not be sure). Plus it is very depressing at times to see changes like capitalization of "thank you" or even adding "good day sirs" - so for proper review you'd need to add comment slowing things down even more...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Point was quite much what **rene** wrote in the first comment: _For the other edits it is indeed true that both you and higher reps are working of the same list, leading to conflicts._ To put it in other words again: if higher reps would work primarily on some  flag & edit review lists instead of triage, first posts & late answers there could be less edit conflicts in three last mentioned queues AND 2 first mentioned queues might be purged a bit faster (as a side effect not as a primary request or so).

Comment: @pirho I believe "prioritize their valuable time in Stack Overflow better" is almost opposite of "would work primarily on some flag & edit review lists instead of triage, first posts & late answers" from my point of view... You may want to [edit] your comment into the post to clarify... (Also I seriously doubt there will be much discussion without concrete proposal on your side  - even more targeted posts on "how to improve participation in CV queue" yet to yield any useful results)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well if you mean the word "primarily" in my comment maybe it was not the best choice but prefer higher rep queues over lower rep queues if it makes any difference. And I agree on that that I should have some idea where to start to have discussion. Maybe I will have if I someday have enough rep to do the same prioritizing myself that I want others to do and also might then understand your point of view better.

Comment: @pirho no, I tried to point out that if one "prioritize their valuable time" then reviewing in general is less beneficial than answering or direct edits (and reviewing is likely less satisfying for most people). If your main concern is which queue to pick first *after* one decided to do review you should definitely clarify it in the post.